# Will concrete overhang interfere with replacing my door?

Tags: doors, carpentry, weatherproof

I'm going to be replacing my front door in a few days, along with adding a sill pan as one isn’t present.

My concrete porch butts up to the threshold of the door and extends about 2 inches. So it looks like a sill pan won’t be able to be installed as normal.

Is this going to be a problem when I go to install the new door? Does this negate the need for a sill pan?

[image]

Comment: Need more pics.

Comment: I'm confused about what I'm looking at. Maybe post a photo from a more human perspective. Which part is the porch? You describe it as extending, but it seems to be _below_ the house floor.